# Refactor, Organize Usings commands missing from Visual Studio context menu

Tags: visual-studio

In VS 2010, Silverlight, C#.  I have multiple .cs files.  In some of them the 'Refactor' and 'Organize Usings' (among other items) in the right-click context menu are missing.

Why are they missing? How can they be brought back?

Comment: Let me add a little more detail:  the .cs files affected are all client side; the .Web project .cs files all work fine.  So this isn't limited to Visual Studio itself.

Comment: And more:  I started a new project of the same type (Navigation App) and the client on this new one has all the proper context menus.  Tomorrow I will copy all my code across and see what happens.  I'm sleepy now, though.  ;o

Comment: Ok. I still do not have all the details but perhaps I can point anyone who has this similar problem in a (hopefully) helpful direction. This was the result of a programming error. Yes!! A programming error!! My IDE changed in quite an unexpected way because of an error in my XAML and/or namespaces. My guess is that VS decided that it could not perform refactoring or using sorts because of the error -- but instead of telling me, or simply disabling the choices, it chose to remove them completely and (at least from the context menu pov) act like nothing was wrong.

Comment: Specifically, I had added a converter to one of my bindings.  Either the converter was wrong, the namespacing for the converter, or the syntax somewhere between there.  

Well, that's the push in the right direction.  As I have time I'll revisit it and find specifically what is wrong.  Currently I have to complete this project.  I just hope these points are helpful to someone:  and the main point is that it was not the IDE simply "breaking" but (a bug in?) the IDE responding to a programming error.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on Visual Studio 2012.  I have several projects in my solution and it only appears to be doing this on the interface project. So far, none of the suggestions below have helped...anyone else have any ideas?  Intellisense isn't working right in this project either.  Very annoying.

Answer (score 65):

I had the same problem after installing ReSharper. "Organize Usings > Remove and Sort" and some other shortcuts were missing in the context menu.

You can still invoke the commands (when availiable) via

```
Edit > Intellisense > Organize Usings > Remove and Sort
```

To show them in the context menu again (in case of ReSharper causing the trouble) goto

```
ReSharper > Options... > Environment > Keyboard & Menus > Menus & Toolbars >
   Uncheck 'Hide overridden Visual Studio Menu items'
```

Comment: Just for info, this is documented by JetBrains here: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/84269548-There-are-no-Visual-Studio-items-in-context-menu

Comment: That raises the question of what Resharper has overridden these commands *with*. Does it provide a better option?

Comment: More to the point, why oh why does ReSharper do this in the first place?  Implement your own version of something, fine, but why hide the built-in VS commands?

Comment: Thanks it helped. I upgraded my resharper version and lost this context item that I used heavily to clean up my code files.

Comment: Even after unchecking that "Hide overridden..." box the functionality still does not work.  Resharper must be overriding it with nothing. How can I enable this again without removing all Resharper's overridden refactorings? Resharper does a great job of other refactors.

Comment: This solved it, but it's an odd solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698011/remove-unnecessary-usings-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is that the files without the Refactor option are not in your solution.  I have seen this when I was unintentionally looking at files in a different repository branch.

Comment: This was it for me too!  ARGH... glad I'm not crazy tho :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue today and the problem was caused by a merge error where additional data had been added to the .csproj file unintentionally.

```
<Compile Include="DataQueries\Custom\General\CustomImageQueries.cs" />
<Compile Include="DataQueries\Custom\General\CountryQueries.cs" />
<Compile Include="DataQueries\Custom\General\CurrencyQueries.cs" />
<Compile Include="DataQueries\Custom\General\CustomApplicationQueries.cs" />
<Compile Include="DataQueries\Custom\General\CustomFileQueries.cs" />
<Compile Include="DataQueries\Custom\General\CustomImageQueries.cs" />
```

The **CustomImageQueries.cs** entry had been added twice to the .csproj file and once the duplicate entry was removed, the IDE worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I figured my issue out.

I had a XAML workflow file located in the interface project (to allow editing) that I was opening with the file system and passing to another project to process the workflow.

The XAML file had a warning about including System.Runtime even though I had added a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.

I excluded the XAML file from the project and intellisense and the menu options returned.  I then added the file back to the project and they continued to work.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

It appends to me after a 'undo pending change' of an unshelve (TFS).
Added files in shelveset opened in editor remain opened after undo, then you cannot access 'Organize Usings' right-click context menu item.

See ya,
Lun@ir.