# "Remove unnecessary usings" not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with a few projects. `Remove unnecessary usings` is working in all projects except for one.

Why does the `Remove unnecessary usings` command **not** work in some projects?

**Edit** - As you can see in the *Before* image there is no `Remove unnecessary usings` command and if you try to right-click in the file, then `Organize usings > Remove unnecessary usings` does nothing. After setting the project build warning level to 4 the `Remove unnecessary usings` command appears and works.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Looks like this is a VS bug - have you reported it on Connect?

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't realize this was a bug. I will report it tomorrow.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/39043332/6329629

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the `Build` section of the `project properties` there is a setting called `Errors and warnings` which should be `4`.

[image]

Comment: It's not at *all* clear what this answer has to do with your question. Are you sure that the warning level affects removing unnecessary using directives? That sounds unlikely. Which version of VS are you using? It would help if you'd show a short but complete example where it fails.

Comment: @JonSkeet I changed the title and the tag to specify that I'm using VS2015. I changed the warning level from 3 to 4 to fix the problem and I wanted to document that here.

Comment: Please show a short example so that others can try to reproduce.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added some pictures and an explanation. Hope it's clear enough now.

Comment: It would be easier to reproduce with text instead of images - so we can copy/paste instead of typing it in...

Comment: @JonSkeet You don't have to type anything. Just adding a new class is enough to reproduce this.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Why does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 9):

Needing to set the `Warning Level` to 4 for code analyzers to fire [is a Roslyn known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20377).

Additionally, check your projects' Code Analysis rules (project properties > Code Analysis > Open). We had CS8019 and IDE0005 disabled, which prevents the code fix from being offered and the unused using(s) from being highlighted, respectively.

Comment: Thanks! This solved our problem. We had accidentally set CS8019 to None. Changed it to Warning and it worked instantly.