# What is the static analysis rule to warn about unused using statements?

Tags: code-analysis, fxcop, stylecop, static-code-analysis

Is there any FxCop or StyleCop that warns when there is an using statement that is no longer referenced by any object in the file?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/32698011/6329629

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the rule `IDE0005  C# Using directive is unnecessary.` in the category `Style`.

Comment: Did not work for me, also not when I tried https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/28114.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Udo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39085249/6329629) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041686/6329629) answer, I also needed to uncheck **Suppress results from generated code (managed only)** which can be found under **Properties > Code Analyses**.

So all in all:

1. Set the Warning Level to 4 for code analyzers to fire.
2. Set rules CS8019 and IDE0005 to warning in your projects' Code Analysis rules (**Properties > Code Analysis**).
3. Make sure to uncheck **Suppress results from generated code (managed only)** which can be found under **Properties > Code Analyses**.